Docker Container running service on 7080, but canot access port 4200
Maybe a dumb question, but my docker is running a reverse proxy.
The container port 7080 has been mapped to 7080 on my local machine.
When the proxy calls:  localhost/127.0.0.1:4200 (which is not in the container), I get:
I also have other microservers on other ports, but not in the Docker Container (just in the reverse proxy)
~/Desktop/Start Up/Spring Boot/ReverseProxy
docker run -it -p 7080:7080 frontiers/reverse-proxy:latest

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)

2024-08-28T16:32:31.267Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] c.e.r.ReverseProxyApplicationKt          : Starting ReverseProxyApplicationKt v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17-ea with PID 1 (/app/app.jar started by app in /app)
2024-08-28T16:32:31.276Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] c.e.r.ReverseProxyApplicationKt          : The following 1 profile is active: "ssl"
2024-08-28T16:32:35.044Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=5d9f1ed3-ebd3-35da-aad3-7251319adfa7
2024-08-28T16:32:37.977Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [After]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.979Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Before]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.980Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Between]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.980Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Cookie]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.980Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Header]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.980Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Host]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.980Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Method]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.981Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Path]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.982Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Query]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.982Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [ReadBody]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.982Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [RemoteAddr]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.983Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [XForwardedRemoteAddr]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.983Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Weight]
2024-08-28T16:32:37.984Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [CloudFoundryRouteService]
2024-08-28T16:32:38.585Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoints beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-08-28T16:32:39.409Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 7080 (http)
2024-08-28T16:32:39.504Z DEBUG 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] o.s.c.g.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter      : New routes count: 0
2024-08-28T16:32:39.511Z  INFO 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [           main] c.e.r.ReverseProxyApplicationKt          : Started ReverseProxyApplicationKt in 9.698 seconds (process running for 11.461)
2024-08-28T16:33:25.280Z DEBUG 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: angular-server
2024-08-28T16:33:25.281Z DEBUG 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:7080/angular-ui/home] to Route{id='angular-server', uri=http://localhost:4200/angular-ui, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/angular-ui/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[], metadata={}}
2024-08-28T16:33:25.281Z DEBUG 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [c87999ef-1] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@3922ea7
2024-08-28T16:33:25.284Z DEBUG 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted gatewayFilterFactories: [[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@45d46254}, order = -2147483648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@4f2fdf3d}, order = -2147482648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@6c36051c}, order = -1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@1a4cbcc6}, order = 0], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@56402642}, order = 0], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@a240452}, order = 10000], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@620572db}, order = 10150], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@7cecab19}, order = 2147483646], GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=com.example.reverseproxy.routing.filters.DedupeResponseFilterConfig$$Lambda$530/0x0000000800ff4800@6ef4297d}, [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@4c000cc4}, order = 2147483647], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@460e5ffe}, order = 2147483647]]
2024-08-28T16:33:25.317Z DEBUG 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [or-http-epoll-2] g.f.h.o.ObservedRequestHttpHeadersFilter : Will instrument the HTTP request headers [Host:"localhost:7080", Pragma:"no-cache", Cache-Control:"no-cache", sec-ch-ua:""Chromium";v="128", "Not;A=Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="128"", sec-ch-ua-mobile:"?0", sec-ch-ua-platform:""macOS"", Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:"1", User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", Sec-Fetch-Site:"same-origin", Sec-Fetch-Mode:"navigate", Sec-Fetch-Dest:"document", Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate, br, zstd", Accept-Language:"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8", Forwarded:"proto=http;host="localhost:7080";for="192.168.65.1:57263"", X-Forwarded-For:"192.168.65.1", X-Forwarded-Proto:"http", X-Forwarded-Port:"7080", X-Forwarded-Host:"localhost:7080"]
2024-08-28T16:33:25.324Z DEBUG 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [or-http-epoll-2] g.f.h.o.ObservedRequestHttpHeadersFilter : Client observation  {name=http.client.requests(null), error=null, context=name='http.client.requests', contextualName='null', error='null', lowCardinalityKeyValues=[http.method='GET', http.status_code='UNKNOWN', spring.cloud.gateway.route.id='angular-server', spring.cloud.gateway.route.uri='http://localhost:4200/angular-ui'], highCardinalityKeyValues=[http.uri='http://localhost:7080/angular-ui/home'], map=[class io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample='io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample@76a69ecc', class io.micrometer.core.instrument.LongTaskTimer$Sample='SampleImpl{duration(seconds)=0.002643757, duration(nanos)=2643757.0, startTimeNanos=329278823864}'], parentObservation={name=http.server.requests(null), error=null, context=name='http.server.requests', contextualName='null', error='null', lowCardinalityKeyValues=[exception='none', method='GET', outcome='SUCCESS', status='200', uri='UNKNOWN'], highCardinalityKeyValues=[http.url='/angular-ui/home'], map=[class io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample='io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample@a84297c', class io.micrometer.core.instrument.LongTaskTimer$Sample='SampleImpl{duration(seconds)=0.072905828, duration(nanos)=7.2905828E7, startTimeNanos=329208776089}'], parentObservation=null}} created for the request. New headers are [Host:"localhost:7080", Pragma:"no-cache", Cache-Control:"no-cache", sec-ch-ua:""Chromium";v="128", "Not;A=Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="128"", sec-ch-ua-mobile:"?0", sec-ch-ua-platform:""macOS"", Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:"1", User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", Sec-Fetch-Site:"same-origin", Sec-Fetch-Mode:"navigate", Sec-Fetch-Dest:"document", Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate, br, zstd", Accept-Language:"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8", Forwarded:"proto=http;host="localhost:7080";for="192.168.65.1:57263"", X-Forwarded-For:"192.168.65.1", X-Forwarded-Proto:"http", X-Forwarded-Port:"7080", X-Forwarded-Host:"localhost:7080"]
2024-08-28T16:33:25.544Z DEBUG 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [or-http-epoll-2] .o.ObservationClosingWebExceptionHandler : An exception occurred and observation was not previously stopped, will stop it. The exception was [io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:4200]
2024-08-28T16:33:25.624Z ERROR 1 --- [ReverseProxy] [or-http-epoll-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [c87999ef-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/angular-ui/home"

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:4200
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/angular-ui/home" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:166) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:131) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:359) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:715) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:692) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:491) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:399) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994) ~[netty-common-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.111.Final.jar!/:4.1.111.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]

I use this to start the docker: docker run -it -p 7080:7080 test/reverse-proxy:latest
UPDATE
Docker Compose file
services:
  app:
    image: test/reverse-proxy:latest
    ports:
      - "7080:7080"
    environment:
      # Server settings
      - SCHEME=http
      - HOST=host.docker.internal

      # Reverse proxy
      - REVERSE_PROXY_PORT=7080

      # BFF server
      - BFF_SERVER_PORT=9090
      - BFF_SERVER_PREFIX=/bff

      # Angular UI server
      - ANGULAR_SERVER_PORT=4200
      - ANGULAR_SERVER_PREFIX=/angular-ui

Docker File
# Use an official Java runtime as a parent image
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

# Create user to run the app as (instead of root)
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# User user "app"
USER app

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the JAR file into the container
COPY build/libs/ReverseProxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar

# Set the command to run the JAR file
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]


show  your docker and docker compose file first, information here is not enough to so we can only guess, please provide more info to pin point the issue and suggest a solution. as you said port is mapped its not only docker file you do have docker compose too i guess.

Just based on the text and the log messages, it seems like you're proxying to 127.0.0.1:4200, where in Docker 127.0.0.1 almost always refers to the current container; but in the text you say the target service isn't in a container.  Do you need a setup as described in From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?

I've added my Docker config files too
